# What does "mostly" modify?

Tags: adverbs

"My friends are mostly non-smokers."

Is "mostly" a focusing adverb that modifies "non-smokers"?

Comment: The term “focusing adverb” is not one that native speakers are normally taught. Perhaps you should try [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). However, given that *non-smokers* is a noun, traditional analysis would forbid using an **adverb** to modify a noun.

Comment: What could it, and what could it not?

Comment: "Most of my friends are non-smokers." or "My friends are mostly non-smoking." (of the non-smoking type)

Comment: What @tchrist said. Obviously adverbial ***mostly*** modifies the verb form ***are***. It's not really credible to see it as modifying ***smokers*** - in practical terms, someone is either a smoker or not. So I think this is General Reference.

Comment: My friends are not exclusively of the set of non-smokers. But all but a few of them belong to that set. Using 'mostly' just makes conveying the above description of the smoking status of your friends far less awkward. 'Mostly' applies to the set 'my friends'.

Answer (score 5):

*Mostly* is an adverb modifying the verb *are*, and means ‘on the whole’. Its grammatical function is no different from a number of other adverbs you might put in its place, such as *predominantly, mainly, largely, principally* or *primarily*.

Comment: Well, since _are_ has no meaning, it's hard to think of _mostly_ modifying it. Equivalent phrases like _on the whole, for the most part, by and large, generally speaking_ modify the entire clause rather than the auxiliary verb for the predicate noun _non-smokers._

Comment: Semantically, _mostly_ is a quantifier (as are all the equivalent phrases), and can be derived from _Most of my friends are non-smokers_ by Quantifier float. (cf. _All of my friends are non-smokers_ ==>  _My friends are all non-smokers_). The fact that _most_ has to be marked as an adverb _mostly_ when it's floated to an adverbial position (_*My friends are most non-smokers_) is simply a regularity that doesn't apply to all floated quantifiers.

Comment: @John: Different syntactic function, but [*"My friends are **most** impressed"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22my+friends+are+most+impressed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is certainly *valid*, if dated. And it means something very different to *"My friends are **mostly** impressed"*.

Comment: @JohnLawler You assert that "are" has no meaning, but I beg to differ.  [Are](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/are) - second person singular present and first, second, third person plural present of be.

Comment: @Lumberjack: Sorry, I mis-wrote. I should have said that _be_ has no meaning; _are_ does of course have the meaning of its inflections; I suppose you could say the _be_ has the meaning "infinitive", since that's its only possible inflection.

Comment: @Lumberjack: I'd argue that _be_ (in its link-verb role) is semantically empty - it is a syntactic place-holder deemed necessary in English. A kiddy would get his point across with 'Billy cold'; we prefer a place-holder in the traditional verb slot, and use 'Billy is cold' where Billy would hardly be described as doing any 'ising'. 'Cold' modifies 'Billy'.

Comment: @JohnLawler, no, no, you were right. You were right that 'are' has no "meaning". It does feature some grammatical categories such as Person, unlike the infinitive to be, but to no extent at all is it a content word, but rather, a pure function word. Those of course have no meaning other than to fasten content words in a sentence. 'Are' is a linking, copulative verb in this sentence (unlike in We think; therefore, we are). Copulative verbs such as 'seem' might have some iota of content, but a copula made from 'to be' is totally empty (save for acting as a syntactic glue).

Comment: @Lumberjack  oops I totally overlooked some comments. I guess I beat the dead horse in my previous comment.

Comment: No, _cold_ doesn't modify _Billy_ in _Bill is cold_. _Cold_ is the predicate, and predicates don't modify their subjects. _Be_ is just the auxiliary for the predicate adjective _cold_ that carries the obligatory tense. Predicates that are adjectives and nouns require auxiliary _be_ to carry the tense; predicates that are verbs can already be inflected for tense, so the _be_ isn't necessary. The point is that _be_ doesn't have **any** meaningful uses; it's **always** an auxiliary, and is treated like one.

Comment: @John Lawler That depends on what your definition of 'modify' is. At http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/modifier is a very broad semantically-based definition:

<<In grammar, to modify is to change or add to the meaning of another word. A modifier is a word or group of words that does this. Adjectives modify nouns ...>>  If you prefer a more syntactically-based definition, I'm stuck with the clumsy " 'Cold' is telling us something about 'Billy'."

Comment: Well, that's no help, then. "Modify" is sposta be a grammatical term, not a semantic one.

Comment: @John Lawler: Terminology apart (although if you can come up with a separate term for 'A ____ is a word or group of words used to change or add to the meaning of another word' I'll use it instead), I'm far happier with your classification of 'mostly' as a quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb *mostly* has at least two meanings.

**1) for the greatest part, in large part, almost entirely**
*Your post is mostly a copy/paste.

My new shirt is made mostly of cotton, with only a small percentage of polyester. These are mostly silver, but we have them in gold too.*
**2) on many or most occasions, usually.**
*She studies mostly at night, but sometimes during the day too. She mostly studies at night, but on an odd occasion she does goes out.*
3) chiefly  [I am not 100% certain this meaning exists, but I see it in some dictionaries.]
*This is mostly a question of ethics.*

Your statement allows for all three meanings:

1) most of your friends are non-smokers (via: it is almost eniterely true that all your friends are such that they are non-smokers (some adverbs [can](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adverbs.htm) be moved to the beginning of a sentence));
2) all of your friends are, on most occasions, non-smokers, but on a chance occasion they are so disposed as to be smokers;
3) your friends are, which is more important than anything else of importance in this matter, non-smokers ("— that they are Big Tobacco apologists and marijuana consumers, is of lesser importance in this discussion about how to raise kids not to become smokers!").

Let us put aside the meaning 3). Most probably, you were implying the meaning 1). Still, only somewhat less probable is that you were intending to express both 1) AND 2), even if subconsciously.

As a reminder, adverbs can modify verbs, adverbs, and adjectives; adverbs cannot modify nouns. In different terms, on the level of sentence syntax, adverbials can modify predicates, adverbials and attributes; adverbials cannot modify one-word subjects and one-word objects.

**The adverbial *mostly* modifies the entire nominal predicate *are non-smokers*** (which consists of the copulative verb "to be" in the third person plural present form and of the predicative nominal *non-smokers*, which in turn is just a prefixed noun). Your *mostly* **does not modify the verb *are* with disregard** of that verb's having a copulative function in the sentence's syntactic structure. Not that a thing of that sort would be impossible: one can say, accompanied by either articulated or written emphasis, *My friends mostly ARE non-smokers, whereas your friends mostly WERE non-smokers.*, where *mostly* has little to do with the rest of the predicate, such like in the following sentence which doesn't even feature a compound predicate, and thus in which *are* is not copulative: *We think; therefore we are, just as Descartes' coevals thought and therefore were.*

A subject with a nominal predicate is akin to an adjective-modified noun (in which the adjectival function is performed by an attributive noun): a phrase *John is asshole* is akin to the phrase *asshole John.* Both phrases can equally plausibly be imagined as a one-sentence retort in same contentious situation. In terms of word classes: [noun][copulative verb][noun] is akin to [adjective][noun]. Syntactically expressed: [SUBJECT][NOMINAL PREDICATE] is akin to [ATTRIBUTE][SUBJECT]. Likewise, *friends are non-smokers* is akin to *non-smoker friends*, and *my friends are non-smokers* is akin to *my non-smoker friends* (ordering of determiners and adjectives is subject to [rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Adjective_order)). How to insert *mostly* into this? Simply. Adverbials can modify attributes, and *my* is an attribute. Can a pronoun *my* be the attribute in a sentence? Sure; when pronouns are used to modify a noun rather than stand in for it, they function as adjectives/determiners; it's known to all that adjectives are attributes, on the syntactic level, and likewise are determiners attributes. Now that it's established that *my* is an attribute, and because we are reminded that adverbials can modify attributes, we know that we are allowed to insert *mostly*, and we deduce that:

The phrase *my friends are mostly non-smokers* is akin to a phrase *mostly my non-smoker friends*.

But, wait, it's already been established that an adverbial cannot modify an attribute! In the latter phrase, the adverbial *mostly* stands right before the attribute *my non-smoker*, as though trying to modify it. ¡No pasarán! OK, but an adverbial can modify a predicate—and that's what it, actually, does, albeit implicitly; so, let us discover what predicate that is in this incomplete sentence implied, our adverbial modifies. And let's include it, thus completing the sentence (save for punctuation).

- *mostly my non-smoker friends exist*
  Or, by reintroducing the less existential synonym:
  *mostly my non-smoker friends are*

That sentence consists of the words identical to those of the original one (though the reordering of words has changed the sentence's meaning).

This compels the realization that, in order to use the adverb *mostly* in a way that without the average listener's puzzlement DOES NOT MODIFY the sole predicative nominal, but, more clearly, modifies the entire nominal predicate (it can also modify the entire clause, but in the provided example it so happens that it is nonsensical to attempt to qualify that clause by *mostly*, so obviously the adverb modifies something other than the entire clause), one might choose to place *mostly* at the beginning of a sentence. (A comma is therein necessary.) Like this:

- Mostly, my friends are non-smokers.

There is no ambiguity any more as to what part of sentence *mostly* modifies. There is a comma, so no one in their right mind would think it modifies the subject. This is meaningless: "very, woman."

"No ambiguity" is there—syntactically. That's helpful for school testing. :) Semantically, or perhaps pragmatically, there might remain that ambiguity, which meaning of *mostly* was intended: 1), 2), or 1) & 2). Your example is not most exemplary of the problem at hand, as "being a non-smoker" is an action/state that cannot be incomplete, except in the sense of continuity. Taking "always" for the time of of action/state, you cannot 'partially "be a non-smoker" '; however, when the meaning permits discontinuity, as the chronological version of *mostly* does, you can still "be a non-smoker" even if you take a puff once in a blue moon. I give here a different example, more illustrative: *Soft drinks are mostly sugar.* For the action/state of "being sugar", both frequency and integrity indeed are modifiable.

One other point. Adverbs normally go after the subject and before the verb. For example, *Dogs often bark.* However, when the predicate contains a copula, the adverb normally goes after the copula: *War is always hell*. "Normally" mainly refers to the lack of emphasis, which implies articulation (cf: *War is ALWAYS hell.*) and/or [pragatically neutral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order) stressing of the sentence elements (*War is hell always.* Always is war hell.)

So, in the sentence *My friends are non-smokers.*, the adverb *mostly* is positioned in a **normal** fashion. Even though it's positioned after the verb, it doesn't modify something other than the predicate. When an adverb is put at the beginning of a sentence, it receives additional stress, additional importance. The so generated nuance may be unsuitable for someone's intended meaning.

Finally, I've found on the internet a similar question: *Cotton fiber is mostly composed of celluose. or Cotton fiber is composed mostly of cellulose?*

In the first sentence, analogous to your example, the adverbial *mostly* modifies the adjectival predicate *is composed of cellulose*. In the second sentence, the adverbial *mostly* modifies the attribute *composed of cellulose* (we've established that adverbials can modify attributes), which acts as a predicative adjective part of the entire adjectival predicate *is composed of cellulose*, which predicative adjective in turn consists of two components of which both are acting as adjectives and are set in the "adjective-modified adjective" form (such as *hot red*, which is evidently [adjective[adjective]]), in which form the first adjectivally-functioning component is actually an adjectival passive (past participle) *composed*, and the second adjectivally-functioning component is the adjectival phrase *of cellulose*, which is composed of the preposition *of* and the noun *cellulose*. OK, that sentence was a mouthful and a headfull.

Please correct my mistakes if and when you discover them.

Comment: Thank you SO much for the sensational answer and all the effort that you expended.