# Can the verb 'be' be modified by a prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, be

There's [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127379/can-the-verb-be-be-modified) about whether it's possible to modify the verb *be*, but the main focus there is on modification by adverbs, not prepositional phrases.

I found some legitimate instances of *be* being modified by a prepositional phrase:

> - *Are you Mr. Thomas, **by** any chance?*
> - *She is here **by** choice.* <sup>(Although it sounds less natural than *She came here by choice.*)</sup>
> - ***From** now on, I am the boss.*
> - *Well, **at** any rate, the next meeting will be on Wednesday.*

But it seems to me that prepositional phrases mostly modify other verbs. Compare:

> - *The door was **opened by** me.*
> - <sup>?</sup>*The door **was** open **by**  me.*

So my question is, **as a general rule, when is it possible to modify the verb *be* with a prepositional phrase and when is it not?**

Comment: Judging by your examples, it depends on the object of the preposition.  *by chance, by choice, from now on,* and *at any rate* are acceptable, but *by me* is not.

Comment: You'll have to distinguish between forms of the verb *to be* that are predicates and forms that are auxiliaries.   You'll also have to distinguish between modifiers and asides.