# "Stories are so much a part of our lives that many people seldom think about them." : The use of 'so' and 'so much' as intensifiers

Tags: grammar, adverbs, copular-verbs, intensifying-adverbs

There are 176 hits in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for *[be] so much a part of*, including the title and:

> 1- It actually is **so much** a part of life.
> 2- Law is **so much** a part of me, I don't think I'll ever be able to let loose of it.
> 3- The computer is **so much** a part of her sons' lives that they sometimes bring a laptop when they visit family in the East Bay.

Other similar examples from COCA:

> 4- it is **so much** a pleasure to have you here.
> 5- And your film is **so much** a woman's story, a young woman story.
> 6- I am **so much** my mother's child in that respect. I hear myself channeling her in so many ways.

Other examples from COCA featuring *so* alone:

> 7- I go to farmers' markets all the time. Field-to-table is **so** my thing.
> 8- Oh, yeah! This is **so** my type of wish!
> 9- "That is so fucking bizarre," she says. "But it 's **so** your mom."
> 10- Dude, try it. This is **so** the bomb.
> 11- If you want to hire me, this is **so** the wrong way to go about it.
> 12- even though she's dead tired and she's been up all night in labor, the minute her baby calls, she is **so** there.
> 13- He was **so** here, he pressed with impossible mass against the Earth.

*[Be] so much a part of* seems to be a special case, or even an idiom†, but I have more general questions:

1- What does *so much* modify in the sentences above? The verb *be*?‡
2- If yes, can *be* be freely modified by *so much*? If not, when exactly can *be* be modified by *so much*?
3- Why doesn't *so* alone work in *[be] so a part of*? (There are 2 hits for it in COCA (compare with the 176 mentioned above)) In other words, when exactly can *be* be modified by *so* alone?<sup>§</sup>

---

Note: In all the examples above, the predicative complements are noun phrases. I think things get more familiar and a lot easier to explain (for me at least) when the complement after *so* or *so much* is an adjective or something (but this post is not about that):

-*Hi! You're so hot!*
+*Thanks! You're so much hotter than me!*
-*I'm so*(/*so much*) *in love with you*!
+*Wow! I'm so married to you!*

---

† <sub>You can see that the title and #3 have *that* after *so much*, #2 suggests that *that*, and #1 doesn't have the *that*. I'm not sure how big of a difference it makes in the meaning, or how relevant it is to my general concerns here.</sub>
‡ <sub>Note that the verb *be* [**is** modifiable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127379/can-the-verb-be-be-modified).</sub>
<sub>§ One casual theory states that when the situation is gradable (or perceived as such) *so much* works better, and when it's non-gradable *so* may be fitter. Compare #2 to #10 for example. (or any of #1-#6 to any of #7-#13)</sub>

Comment: In "I'm so marrying you" and examples 7-11, 'so' is a synonym of 'really' or 'quite'. It feels a little novel, like someone is making up a new turn of phrase. Not ungrammatical but a new thing.

Comment: @Mitch Do you suggest that _I am so much my mother's child_ is an established or familiar use of _so much_? And that there is something different between that and _I am so my mother's child_?

Comment: Fard, yes I feel something different. "I am so tired" is perfectly standard. "I am so a child" (where it is synonymous with really) sounds like 'because science' or 'Knives are hurty', playing with syntax/morphology. But "I am so much my mother's child" sounds natural. (note "I am so a child" can mean with different intonation "I am too a child"

Comment: Perhaps I'm stating the obvious, but I think *so much* tends to be used as a quantitative intensifier while *so* on its own tends to be used as a qualitative intensifier. This is evidenced by the combined phrase [*so much so*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/so+much+so).

Answer (score 5):

The phrase *so much* is modifying the noun phrase *a part of x* in these examples. It isn't modifying the verb *BE*. We most often see this pattern when adverbs like *so, too* or *as* are modifying an adjective which in turn modifies a noun phrase:

- so forceful a blow
- too convenient an excuse
- as brutal an attack

Notice that these adverbs can also modify the word *much*:

- He was too much a part of us, to let anything bad happen to him
- The lobbyists as much a part of the political system as the political parties themselves.

In the examples above they are being used with the noun phrase *a part of X*. However, we can use them with any noun phrase as appropriate:

- He's too much a gentleman to be a scholar.
- Fuseli's Macbeth is as much a hero as a villain.

Comment: Very well. +1. But, 1: Why can't we say that _so (much)_ modifies the verb? 2: Your noun phrases are all of the form _a X_, which can be modified as you demonstrated, but what about noun phrases like _my mother's child_ in "_I'm so / so much my mother's child._"? 3: I still don't understand why sometimes _so_ fits and _so much_ doesn't, or vice versa (my third question in the original post). Why can't we say "_I'm so much here if you need me._" or "_Stories are so a part of our lives._"? All I know is they don't feel right, but I can't analyze them.

Comment: There is confusion here between the modern use of so + noun (This is so the bomb) and so + noun (This is so my type of wish) Completely different from so much.It only began in the nineties and is spoken register.

Answer (score 1):

There's two totally different things going on there.

1)

"so much" is synonymous with "such", eg

*"Law is so much a part of my life"* = *"Law is such a part of my life"*

2)

Using "so" on it's own, as an **intensifier** (as in "I'm so marrying you!"), is a relatively modern informal (ie ungrammatical) usage, and is often used for comic effect, possibly **because** it is so ungrammatical.

Comment: What about "_I am so much my mother's child in that respect._"? Surely doesn't mean "_I am such my mother's child in that respect._", and shows that these two aren't that different, because you can replace _so much_ with _so_ without a change in the meaning: "_I am so my mother's child in that respect._"

Comment: You're right, sorry: i suppose it varies depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to edit this for corrections and further improvements of answers

Based on your sentences, the use of so and so much would be an intensifier of something that you are measuring despite the fact that they are uncountable. At a certain degree, these words are synonymous with each other.

`so`

> would be synonymous to the word very

`so much`

as an adjective

> is most often use in comparative form of verbs.
>
> In that degree
>
> To that extent.

as an adverb

> So great in quantity, degree, or extent
>
> Equivalent or equal in quantity, degree, or extent

links of references:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/so+much