# mostly / mainly - adverb with a noun?

Tags: adverbs

a penny for your thoughts!

I always learnt that adverbs can only come before (i.e. premodify) adjectives and verbs, e.g.

adj: I am extremely happy

v: I really enjoy football

But I was thinking... in the sentence

- The people at this party are mostly/mainly men,

the adverb is placed beside a noun: but that breaks my previously understood rule. Does that mean that the rule is wrong? Or is this grammatically incorrect, and I should say 'mostly male'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "mostly" modify?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127057/what-does-mostly-modify) Barrie England says: '_Mostly_ is an adverb modifying the verb _are_, and means ‘on the whole’. Its grammatical function is no different from a number of other adverbs you might put in its place, such as _predominantly, mainly, largely, principally_ or _primarily_.' But then John Lawler says: 'Well, since _are_ has no meaning, it's hard to think of _mostly_ modifying it. Equivalent phrases like _on the whole, for the most part,_ ...

Comment: _by and large_, generally speaking modify the entire clause rather than the auxiliary verb for the ... noun [men].'

Comment: Aha, so you could say that mostly doesn't modify the noun 'men' but rather the verb 'to be' - that is pretty obvious now you've said it!!! Thanks for the reference :-)

Comment: No; I'm with John Lawler (usually the safest place to be). 'The people at this party are mostly/mainly men' = 'The people at this party are, for the most part, men' = 'The people at this party are men, for the most part = 'For the most part, the people at this party are men'. The adverb/adverbial qualifies the complete statement (ie 'modifies the whole main clause'): 'For the most part, _the people at this party are men_.' The position immediately before the noun in your original, notwithstanding. The 'rule' you learned fails to mention/consider this sort of sentence. And probably others.

Comment: ... And John Lawler considers 'mostly' a quantifier. _I'm still thinking about this one._

Comment: The 'rules' taught in Anglophone schools are almost always wrong. They focus on the irrelevant points mastered by the textbook authors in their youth, which they declaim with unshakeable authority. And the teachers believe them and the students believe the teachers. No wonder people mostly treat grammar as a way to put people down.

Comment: PS I've stopped using 'learnt'; one person accused me of being uneducated for using it, as being totally unacceptable. I pointed out that he was contradicting what a respectable dictionary actually said. But then FumbleFingers pointed out that it _was_ rather [19]50s-ish – so I listened. _Don't worry about the possible confusion with two-syllable learned.)

Comment: Haha - agreed! Hence why I wrote this... https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01DFY06F6/ref=cm_sw_r_apa_i_kLUQEbY4RSJ5D

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Re *I'm still thinking about this one*. Assuming we accept that *I am mostly heterosexual* is "valid" phrasing it seems to me we have to accept two possible parsings for *The people at this party are mostly heterosexual*. When I started typing this comment I intended to make the case that moving "mostly" to the start or end of the utterance would affect whether we parse it as a "whole sentence adverb" or not, but  I'm not so sure any more. (So ***I'm** still thinking about this one!* :)

Comment: The only way that *mostly* could be modifying *men* is if you're talking about people who are, for example, 95% male and 5% female. In which case, the example sentence would actually mean *they are **all** [mostly men].* (As opposed to only *some* being mostly men.) But I don't think that's the meaning you're talking about here. Since it isn't, *mostly* is modifying *are*, not *men*. However, note that the answer to this question depends entirely on what the intention of the sentence is.