# Can mostly be used to modify a noun

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

> Mostly bikers come to this bar.

In this sentence, I’m trying to say that most of the people that come to this bar are bikers. Can you use mostly to modify bikers in this instance?

Comment: This question has answers for you. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127057/what-does-mostly-modify